# Hide the "-" option in html <select>

Tags: c#, html, css, select, blazor

I have a classic  with  on my razor page. When I start the application, the selection gives me an additional option with the content "-". Does anyone know why and how I can disable that?

[image]

[image]

//EDIT: Expanding the code line to

---

`.Where(s => s.Status != SprintStatus.Active && s.Name != "-")`

Fixed it for me by excluding every entry with the name "-". Although there was no such entry.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: have you tried `.Where(s => s.Status != SprintStatus.Active && s.Name != "-")`? You could also have the `sprints` already filtered with the data you really need

Comment: Almost certainly one `sprite` in `sprites` has a `Name` property of "-".

Comment: First: I'll never upload images of code again, except it's Piet. :D
Second: Thank you! I never thought it would be an entry. In SQL Studio there was no entry with the name "-". But the line from @Cleptus fixed it for me!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No problem But, while Cleptus's answer may have got rid of the entry from the display, it almost certainly didn't fix it.  There's a stay piece of code out there producing the record in sprites that will bite you again if you don't fix it!

Comment: Your data is poluted, your table does contain records it should not (but your are failing to query the wrong data), consider removing the wrong data from your table.